# How to convert Hex to binary in PHP?

Tags: php, hex, byte

I'm trying to send `0x01` HEX as Byte using the `socket_write($socket, XXXX , 1);` function.

There is part of documentation:

> "...If yes, server will reply to module 0x01, if not – replay 0x00.
> Server must send answer – 1 Byte in HEX format."

Comment: `pack()`/`unpack`, or string escapes "\x01".

Comment: I have tried this: 

$data = pack('H*', "0x01");
socket_write($socket, $data , 1);

...but it's not working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are multiple alternatives:

- When using the [`pack()`](http://php.net/pack) function, the string argument to the `H*` format specifier should **not** include the `0x` prefix.

  ```
  pack("H*", "01")
  ```
- To convert a single hex-number into a byte you can also use [`chr()`](http://php.net/chr).

  ```
  chr(0x01)
  ```

  Here PHP first interprets the hex-literal `0x01` into a plain integer `1`, while chr() converts it into a string. The reversal (for socket reading) is [`ord()`](http://php.net/ord).
- The most prevalent alternative is using just using [C-string escapes](http://php.net/types.string#language.types.string.syntax.double):

  ```
  "\x01"
  ```

  Or in octal notation:

  ```
  "\001"
  ```
- [`hex2bin("01")`](http://php.net/hex2bin) works just like `pack("H*")` here. And there's [`bin2hex`](http://php.net/bin2hex) for the opposite direction.