# How to convert Hex to Byte using PHP

Tags: php, hex, byte

I am currently having problem to convert Hex value into byte using PHP. Are there any way to do this?

This is the Hex value I want to convert to Byte : 02 05 12 E6 A3

I have tried pack() function and also chr() function but It didnt helped me on it. Can I know are there any way to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: pack()/unpack, or string escapes "\x01".

Comment: Additional to Deep Kakkars comment here the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513381/php-convert-hex-to-byte

Comment: @DeepKakkar so if i use pack function how to add it?

Comment: You need to use like this <?php echo pack("C3",80,72,80); ?>. what is the problem which are you getting?

Comment: @DeepKakkar what does C3 means?

Comment: The pack() function packs data into a binary string. let me write an aswer for you there.

Answer (score 1):

Choose Pack() function for this task. The pack() function packs data into a binary string. It's syntax is `pack(format,args+)`. `format` is required parameter while `args` is optional. It specifies the format to use when packing data. There are various formats as follows:

```
a - NUL-padded string
A - SPACE-padded string
h - Hex string, low nibble first
H - Hex string, high nibble first
c - signed char
C - unsigned char
s - signed short (always 16 bit, machine byte order)
S - unsigned short (always 16 bit, machine byte order)
n - unsigned short (always 16 bit, big endian byte order)
v - unsigned short (always 16 bit, little endian byte order)
i - signed integer (machine dependent size and byte order)
I - unsigned integer (machine dependent size and byte order)
l - signed long (always 32 bit, machine byte order)
L - unsigned long (always 32 bit, machine byte order)
N - unsigned long (always 32 bit, big endian byte order)
V - unsigned long (always 32 bit, little endian byte order)
f - float (machine dependent size and representation)
d - double (machine dependent size and representation)
x - NUL byte
X - Back up one byte
Z - NUL-padded string
@ - NUL-fill to absolute position
```

**note: The "Z" code was added in PHP 5.5 with the same functionality as "a" for Perl compatibility**