# How do i send a byte stream to a socket with PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

In GO i can do the following:

```golang
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", CONNECT) // Client

request := []byte{01, 00} // The request start with 0100

request = append(request, []byte(`09302020073014323720200730007402`)...) // The request

conn.Write(request)
```

This does work, however, i'm unable to translate this to PHP.

What i have so far:

```php
$fp = stream_socket_client("tcp://x:x", $errno, $errstr, 5);
  if (!$fp) {
      echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
  } else {
      $queryString = '010009302020073014323720200730007402';
    
      fwrite($fp, $queryString);
      echo fgets($fp, $responseSize);
      fclose($fp);
  }
```

I tried using the described solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513381/php-convert-hex-to-byte) with no success, the server does not recognise my input.

Comment: Can you check the return value of `fwrite` to see if the write is actually succeeding? Additionally your query string is most likely being serialized as as a string rather than binary, and as such isn't recognizing the first characters as being the bytes `[]byte{01, 00}`.

Comment: @JohnOss Hey John! The write is successful, I stripped the error handling from the code for brevity

Comment: The programs write different data to the connection.  The Go program starts with the two bytes 0, 1.  The PHP program starts with the four bytes 48, 49, 49, 49.  The rest of the data is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Go example, your request begins with the bytes `0x01`, and `0x00`. In PHP, you're writing the byte encoding of the string `'0100'`. These aren't exactly the same, and you can view how they differ here: https://play.golang.org/p/0gidDZe4lZF

What you really want to be writing is the single byte 0x0, and 0x1 at the beginning of your string instead of these characters.

Using PHP's builtin [chr function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) we can create a string using the single bytes 0x0 and 0x1 like so:

```php
$queryString = chr(0) . chr(1);
$queryString .= '09302020073014323720200730007402'
```

Barring any additional encoding issues on the PHP side of things, that should match your query in your Go example.